# RabbitMQ not starting on windows 10 anymore

Tags: rabbitmq

I am using RabbitMQ to work with Django and Celery on Windows 10.

I have installed RabbitMQ Server 3.8.5 and Erlang OTP 23.

RabbitMQ works when I installed it yesterday, and I managed to configure some tasks with Celery using it.

I could use it earlier in the day, however after a restart, I realised rabbitMQ server won't start anymore. When I try to start the service in services, it shows:

```
A system error has occurred.

System error 1067 has occurred.

The process terminated unexpectedly.
```

I checked the logs, and it shows:

```
{"init terminating in do_boot",{error,{compiler,{"no such file or directory","compiler.app"}}}}
init terminating in do_boot ({error,{compiler,{no such file or directory,compiler.app}}})
```

trying to run rabbitmq-plugins.bat enable rabbitmq_management gives:

```
Failed to start Elixir.
    error: {error,{compiler,{"no such file or directory","compiler.app"}}}
```

Does anyone know what happened? It could work previously and all of a sudden it just doesn't work anymore...

Comment: Did you get a solution for this, I am also facing the same issue.